# Unusual Google Apps Script Execution Behavior in Google Chat

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-chat

I am encountering an unexpected behavior with a Google Apps Script web app when using Google Chat for sharing URLs. Here's the scenario:

**Issue**: The doGet(e) function in my Google Apps Script web app is executed twice (when checking in the logs) without any manual clicking on the URL shared via Google Chat. Additionally, merely pasting the URL into a chat conversation triggers the script's execution.

Web App URL Format: The web app's URL follows this structure: [https://script.google.com/macros/s/{ID}/exec](https://script.google.com/macros/s/%7BID%7D/exec).

**Exploration**: Out of curiosity, I signed up for a random website and received a confirmation link in my email. Without clicking the link or sending any chat messages, I pasted the URL into a Google Chat conversation. Later, when I actually clicked the link, I received a notification stating that my account was already activated.

I am seeking insights and clarification regarding the underlying mechanism causing this behavior. Any guidance or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any link pasted in almost all chat apps triggers a HTTP GET on that url. This is to display a thumbnail of the link by that chat app.

Comment: With regards to Chat API auto previewing links, you may also check this [existing post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188457860#comment3) about it.